# Container View Controller - Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I'm trying to develop Container View Controller as it is shown in Apple documentation.

For now I have simple init code in `viewDidAppear`:

```
presentedVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(Storyboard.yesNoControllerID)
self.addChildViewController(presentedVC)
presentedID = Storyboard.yesNoControllerID
presentedVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds
self.containerView.addSubview(presentedVC.view)
presentedVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

I have implemented exchange method, like in Apple doc:

```
private func exchangeVC(withVC viewController: UIViewController){
    presentedVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    self.addChildViewController(viewController)

    viewController.view.frame = newViewStartFrame
    let endFrame = oldViewEndFrame
    self.containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)

    self.transitionFromViewController(presentedVC, toViewController: viewController, duration: 0.25, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        viewController.view.frame = self.presentedVC.view.frame
        self.presentedVC.view.frame = endFrame
        }) { (finished) in
            self.presentedVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
            self.presentedVC.removeFromParentViewController()
            viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
            self.presentedVC = viewController
    }

}
```

Then, I have button that is calling simply:

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(presentedID)
exchangeVC(withVC: controller)
```

With this code, my controllers are animating on screen on button press. But at the end of animation I'm getting:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for
>   UIViewController: 0x7aecf730.

Can You tell me what I have done wrong? How to get rid of this error/warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Generally, that warning appears when you try to present the same view controller without dismissing it first, but the transition method should handle all that for you. I ended up fixing it by using

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)
```

instead of

```
UIViewController.transition(from:to:duration:options:animations:completion:)
```

as you are above. Of course, I had to manually add and remove the subviews as well. I'm not sure why this change worked, but my best guess is that there's something wrong with the `UIViewController` transition method that issues that warning. Fortunately the fix is really easy.

Comment: I have ended up with by replacing it with segues.

Comment: I have used `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)` to replace `UIViewController.transition(from:to:duration:options:animations:completion:)` because `UIViewController.transition(...)` adds the view to the parent too late and we can see a resizing of the new view(or its subviews) during the animation which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 9):

This is an easy mistake to make, but Apple's documentation for `transition(from:to:duration:options:animations:completion:)` states that:

> This method adds the second view controller's view to the view
>   hierarchy and then performs the animations defined in your animations
>   block. After the animation completes, it removes the first view
>   controller's view from the view hierarchy.

You were getting that `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions` warning because you were adding the subview once with:

`self.containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)`

... then adding it again when calling `transition(from:to:duration:options:animations:completion:)`

Removing the call to `addSubview` would fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I have to add initial constraints so I'm going to use `UIView.animate`, but this is the actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this unbalanced calls error on iPhones, in button tap handler. traced it to a dismiss(animated: no) followed by a present(.. animated: no)

solution was to do the present in a completion handler for the dismiss call.